# Conditional ui-sref and ng-click on same link

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a link in a directive that currently looks like this:

```
<a href="" ng-href="{{tile.type === 'article' ? '/article/' + tile.slug : ''}}" ng-click="tile.type === 'video' && openVideo({id: tile.videoId})"></a>
```

The logic here is this:
 - If `tile.type` is `article`, the link should create an href value and if clicked should go to this relevant url
 - If `tile.type` is `video` the link should leave the href value empty and execute the `openVideo` function when clicked

Problem is, for video links, the href value is completely removed so the link loses native link styling such as the mouse cursor changing on hover. I also would prefer to use `ui-sref` rather than `ng-href` but I can't seem to get conditional statements working in those.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use ng-if:

```
<a ng-if="tile.type === 'article'" ng-href="{{'/article/' + tile.slug}}"></a>
<a ng-if="tile.type === 'video'" href="" ng-click="openVideo({id: tile.videoId})"></a>
```

you can use ui-sref as well

Comment: This way, I would have to repeat any content I put inside the link which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

option 1: use only ng-click and handle links via $state.go inside ng-click function.

option 2: make syntetic parallell route for videos using https://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky or intercept video route change in $stateChangeStart(open video and prevent state change).